# Automatically generate color based on text

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a column of unknown text.

[image]

For each text, I want to give it a color. I don't mind which exact color it is, as long as different text has different color.

In this particular example, A5,A9,A10 will have the same color, different from all other cells.

How do I achieve that? It's fine to sort the column.

Comment: It seems you want to find the duplicate rows. If the order of the list doesn't matter, I would sort the list so the duplicates stand out, and coloring is not a requirement anymore. Other than that, I don't think you can easily do this. There is a limitation on how many colors you can have and for this, you will need VBA macros. SuperUser is not a "Please write me a script"  kind of site though, so the answer you will get here is "its impossible with standard excel."

Answer (score 0):

Both of the methods highlighted below can be used independently but it would be more useful, I think, if you used both together. Hopefully this helps you out.

## Sorting

As @LPChip has said, in Excel the coloring will be limited, a better option would be to sort the data and then all the duplicates would be in adjacent rows making them easier to spot.

You can sort by selecting the column, clicking the *Data* tab and then the AZ icon in the Sort and Filter, to sort alphabetically.

## Conditional Formatting

If you want to add color, I would recommend using this method in conjunction with the sort mentioned above.

First, select the column then click the *Home* tab, next the *Conditional Formatting* drop down menu, then under *Highlight Cells Rules* select *Duplicate Values...*.

After you have applied this, **all** duplicate cells will be the same color.